# RegAsm in Custom Action

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, outlook, windows-installer

I have an Outlook Addin, that's created in Visual Studio 2010 targeting .NET Framework 4.0.

This addin was previously written in VB6 (thus targeting only x86 Outlook).

However, I'm running into problems now because there's 2 versions of Outlook.

I had amended this a few years ago, but have 2 separate MSI files (one targeting x86 and one targeting x64...with respective Launch Conditions in each to prevent the user from installing an incorrect MSI on their Outlook).

However now I'm running into bigger issues...more and more users keep downloading the incorrect version and their getting annoyed.

I was hoping to make 1 installer files and registering the following files.

1. Shim x86
2. Shim x64

I've placed these both in 1 installer file (with the installer targeting x86), and I'm running `RegSvr32` on these via Custom Action by subscribing to the `Commit` event.

Now the problem becomes when I have some .NET DLLs. I have basically a DLL (which is responsible for checking whether or not the registration of a user has been satisfied or not).

For some reason, even though I make a call to the following:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe`

And also for x64 based systems:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe`

The full call to this for my activation DLL and my main DLL is the following:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /tlb MyDll.dll /Codebase`

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /tlb MyDll.dll /Codebase`

The code runs successfully (at least my assumption is that it runs successfully because there are no errors thrown in the `Try/Catch`).

However, when I debug through my application, and make the call to `CreateObject` it just returns back an error stating `ActiveX Component cannot be created`.

So now, the situation becomes more convoluted (and I'm confused as well now) because when I run the commands via an elevated command prompt the code seems to work.

So I have two major questions:

1. Am I running the command(s) correctly in the Custom Action installer?
2. Why does the command work via elevated command prompt (when I *thought* the MSI runs in elevated mode anyways?

I can post more code if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically, I solved this by myself.

Didn't need to use `RegAsm` to register the DLLs.

My two Shims are being registered in a Custom Action installer running during the `Install` method.

I basically run `RegSvr32` to **register both of the Shims on to the system**.

Also, I got rid of Late binding. That call to `CreateObject` was replaced with:

- Importing the external DLL as a reference
- Replacing Late binding with early binding (basically using that DLL's namespace)

After successfully compiling a 32 bit target platform MSI, I was able to install this on x64 Outlook and x86 Outlook.